# MySQL Workbench do not render Columns Tab at ER

Tags: mysql, gui, mysql-workbench

I have a fresh install of **Ubuntu 14.10**, after installing all I need, I started MySQL Workbench `(v.6.1.7 build 1788)` and in it's ER modeling its not showing anything in `Columns` Tab when editing a table, did I miss something or is there a configuration to make it work? This happens too at `Indexes` and `Foreign Keys`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gzOs.png):
[image]

Comment: Same here :(. Ubuntu Mate 14.10. Have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: I found a relevant bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-workbench/+bug/1155571

Comment: Hey, I managed to fix this eventually, but I can't post an answer because your question is locked. If you still need help with this, post a comment here, and I'll write all the instructions on a pastebin or something.

Comment: @VictorStanciu I'll be very thankful if you can do this for us!

Comment: Sure, I wrote the instructions here: https://www.notehub.org/cgkao. I hope they work for you too!

Comment: Thank you very much @VictorStanciu worked like a charm! Hope this help someone else too

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear that!